# How to extend sap.m.ColumnListItem

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, extend

I would like write my own ColumnListItem control to add drag and drop functionality.

So far I've done this:

```
$.sap.require('sap.m.ColumnListItem');
$.sap.declare('my.DraggableDelegate');
$.sap.declare('my.ColumnListItem');
my.DraggableDelegate = function(oControl) {
        this.oControl = oControl;
    };
    my.DraggableDelegate.prototype = { 
        onAfterRendering: function() {
            this.oControl.$().draggable({
                cancel: false
        });
    }
};
sap.m.ColumnListItem.extend("my.ColumnListItem", {
    renderer : {}, // actually I would rather like to get the ColumnListItem renderer but I don't know how ...
    init: function() {
        this.oDraggable = new my.DraggableDelegate(this);
        this.addDelegate(this.oDraggable);                
    }
    // something is still missing here I guess
});
```

The developer console returns just one error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Does anyone know how to extend the sap.m.ColumnListItem control correctly?

Comment: You have to call the `init()` of the super class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to hirse I found the missing line:

```
sap.m.ColumnListItem.extend("my.ColumnListItem", {
    renderer : {},
    init: function() {
        /*******/sap.m.ColumnListItem.prototype.init.apply(this); /******/
        this.oDraggable = new my.DraggableDelegate(this);
        this.addDelegate(this.oDraggable);                
    }
});
```